# How can I show my google analytics traffic report via asp.net or classic asp?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, google-analytics

How can I show my google analytics traffic report (AKA 'View Report') via asp.net or classic asp?

Answer (score 2):

There are several APIs for querying data from Analytics. For example in both [JavaScript](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/1.0/gdataJavascript.html) and [C#](http://www.reimers.dk/blogs/jacob_reimers_weblog/archive/2009/05/09/added-google-analytics-reader-for-net.aspx). See the [developer guide](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html) for more information.

I don't think there is an easy way to just include their report into an existing page. You would have to use the APIs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the google data APIs to pull feed data as xml [look at this tool](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) it lets you run text queries and see the results

then make a call to data feed and parse with Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0") to output the results

im writing an article on how to do it right now ill post here when im done...

Comment: ok i got my post done you can find the code to do Google data APIs in ASP here http://blog.cartercole.com/2010/01/consuming-google-data-apis-with-asp.html