# Is there a way to integrate google analytics reporting in a website

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

One of my clients has requested this feature. They dont want to login to google analytics and want all the tracking/reporting through the site. Is there a way to show reporting inside an asp.net page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise that get hold of the data by access the Google Analytics API by sending an appropriate HTTP request to the analytics account. It will reply by sending an XML feed that you can parse into a database should you wish to or to a flat file.

Here is a link to the [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/)

If you plan to make a dashboard out of that data you'll need to either configure a flash object to listen to the data you've parsed or make use of the HTML5 `<canvas>` object and some javascript if you want on:hover displays of values etc. Depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. The [official Google C# library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Analytics_API) to download data from Google Analytics
2. [A head start on the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/869666) of collecting the data.
3. A CodePlex project to [pull Google Analytics into SQL Server 2008](http://analyticssource.codeplex.com/) using SSIS.
4. An older set of [Google Analytics usercontrols](http://analytics.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.
5. An even older set of [Google Analytics usercontrols](http://gadashboardcontrols.codeplex.com/) with less features(?) on CodePlex.
6. A classic ASP [analytics scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994357/423430) circa Jan 2010.